# /bin/sh: app: not found

Tags: docker, alpine-linux

```
/ # which chasquid-util
/usr/local/bin/chasquid-util
/ # chasquid-util
/bin/sh: chasquid-util: not found
/ # /usr/local/bin/chasquid-util
/bin/sh: /usr/local/bin/chasquid-util: not found
/ # ls -al /usr/local/bin/
total 27432
drwxr-xr-x    1 root     root          4096 Jul 26 16:18 .
drwxr-xr-x    1 root     root          4096 Jul 26 16:18 ..
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root      11721005 Jul 26 16:18 chasquid
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root       5510494 Jul 26 16:18 chasquid-util
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root       2910713 Jul 26 16:18 mda-lmtp
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root       4767277 Jul 26 16:18 smtp-check
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root       3164845 Jul 26 16:18 spf-check
/ #
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given your context, this typically means you are missing a shared library. With alpine, it's typically glibc since they ship with libmusl. You can check this with:

```
ldd chasquid-util
```

I've got several other reasons for this listed in my [DC 2018 slidedeck](https://rawgit.com/sudo-bmitch/dc2018/master/faq-stackoverflow.html#59):

- Did you run the intended command? (e.g. `docker run --rm my_image -it echo hello world` will run the command `-it`)
- Is docker trying to run a json string? (any json paring errors will show up as executing the json as a string)
- Does the file exist... in the path and inside the container? (can't run stuff from the host inside a container without building it into the image or mounting a volume)
- If it is a shell script, check the first line (e.g. `#!/bin/bash`)
- Check for windows linefeeds on linux shell scripts (look for `^M` or `\r` with different editors)
- If it is a binary, there is likely a missing library (use `ldd` to check)

Comment: yes, chasquid is a golang app. I build the chasquid app in alpine and now it works.